# Integrate autoload on scroll with drupal 7 custom module?

Tags: drupal-7

How can we integrate jquery auto load on scroll with our drupal 7 custom module or our drupal queries?

Answer (score 1):

the basic idea would be to find some jquery plugin like http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html which provide to load content on scroll

and integrate that plugin to your custom module using function drupal_add_js()

then on event of jquery plugin scroll make ajax call to load next records